# How to parse a JSON a data point from the following JSON using PHP

Tags: php, html, json, api

I've been trying to parse some JSON to get a piece of data. I'm new to JSON but I think I'm parsing data from a dictionary, within an array that itself is chosen from a dictionary.

I've been trying to parse the metric temperature, from an example below, using the following PHP:

`$temp_c = $parsed_json->{'hourly_forecast'}[0]->{'FCTTIME'}->{'temp'}->{'metric'};`

I used `2` for the 3rd entry of the recurring API response but for this extract it is technically `0`.

The (long) sample is this:

```
{
  "response": {
  "version":"0.1",
  "termsofService":"http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html",
  "features": {
  "hourly": 1
  }
    }
        ,
    "hourly_forecast": [
        {
        "FCTTIME": {
        "hour": "23","hour_padded": "23","min": "00","min_unpadded": "0","sec": "0","year": "2018","mon": "2","mon_padded": "02","mon_abbrev": "Feb","mday": "27","mday_padded": "27","yday": "57","isdst": "0","epoch": "1519772400","pretty": "11:00 PM GMT on February 27, 2018","civil": "11:00 PM","month_name": "February","month_name_abbrev": "Feb","weekday_name": "Tuesday","weekday_name_night": "Tuesday Night","weekday_name_abbrev": "Tue","weekday_name_unlang": "Tuesday","weekday_name_night_unlang": "Tuesday Night","ampm": "PM","tz": "","age": "","UTCDATE": ""
        },
        "temp": {"english": "34", "metric": "1"},
        "dewpoint": {"english": "21", "metric": "-6"},
        "condition": "Mostly Cloudy",
        "icon": "mostlycloudy",
        "icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/nt_mostlycloudy.gif",
        "fctcode": "3",
        "sky": "76",
        "wspd": {"english": "15", "metric": "24"},
        "wdir": {"dir": "ENE", "degrees": "75"},
        "wx": "Mostly Cloudy",
        "uvi": "0",
        "humidity": "60",
        "windchill": {"english": "24", "metric": "-4"},
        "heatindex": {"english": "-9999", "metric": "-9999"},
        "feelslike": {"english": "24", "metric": "-4"},
        "qpf": {"english": "0.0", "metric": "0"},
        "snow": {"english": "0.0", "metric": "0"},
        "pop": "21",
        "mslp": {"english": "30.21", "metric": "1023"}
        }
        ,
        {
        "FCTTIME": {
```

etc

Apologies for any ambiguities or errors, I'm happy to clarify anything. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `FCTTIME` part is your error. `temp` is a sibling of `FCTTIME`, not its child.

Also, you shouldn't need to use the complex (curly brace) syntax for those keys. That's only really needed for things that aren't valid property names, like strings beginning with numbers, etc.

This should work:

```
$temp_c = $parsed_json->hourly_forecast[0]->temp->metric;
```

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't realised they were siblings, that's great. (Won't let me accept the answer yet but I will soon.)

Also delighted to remove some of the clutter from my parsing, have a file load of those.